# Click on a listview background

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a bulk selection actionmode in my app and i want to be able to have it disable when the user clicks outside any items in the list. But when i set an onclick listener for my listview it throws an exception telling me i want to set an item click listener instead (answer - no .. i don't).

i tried setting the list view height to wrap_content but then scrolling becomes sluggish when there are a lot of items in the list.

So I am not sure what to do - possibly i need to get the get the height of the items and use an ontouchlistener to detect if the click is below this height. but how do i do that - and it seem like a lot of work for very little.

Comment: provide some code to understand

Comment: and logcat will help us.